# Вопрос по WordPress ЧПУ

Tags: php, wordpress, чпу

Привет! На сайте установлен Wordpress. Дело в том, что внутри директории с сайтом я создаю дополнительную папку и помещаю туда отдельный скрипт, который, в свою очередь, тоже использует ЧПУ. Но Wordpress не дает открыть папку, из-за чего скрипт открывает 404. Скрипт использует модульную систему, если модули запрашивать по отдельности, то WP показывает свою ошибку 404. Что делать? Поддомен создавать не хочется.

Comment: @Lektor, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163302/how-do-i-ignore-a-directory-in-mod-rewrite
Тут написано, какое правило добавить, чтобы на 1 папку не действовал стандартный ЧПУ Wordpress.

Comment: @cema93, не работает

Comment: Покажите ваш .htaccess.

Comment: @cema93, на данный момент .htaccess имеет следующий вид (в корневой папке, где расположен wordpress): http://jsfiddle.net/76sgs2yt/
____
@cema93, подскажите, пожалуйста, что добавить! ничего из вышеперечисленного не работает.

Comment: Поставь в самое начало .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myfolder - [L,NC]
</IfModule>

Comment: @Get извините за столь долгий комментарий, но: не РАБОТАЕТ! :(

Comment: Почитай про создание правил для htaccess. Не зная реальной ситуации, сложно что-то советовать. По идее, работать должно.

Comment: @Get разобрался! Проблема не в .htaccess, роутер работает неправильно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри .htaccess.
Все запросы к сайту по умолчанию перекидываются на индексный файл wordpress. Добавь строку, аналогичную строке для изображений, чтобы запросы к новой папке не перекидывались на index.php.

Comment: @Get, можете скинуть эту строку?